# Triple DES with 2 keys

Tags: encryption, des, attack, 3des, meet-in-the-middle-attack

Suppose triple DES is performed by choosing two keys $K_1$ and $K_2$ and computing $C = T (T (T (L, K_1), K_2), K_2)$. How to attack this modified version with a meet-in-the-middle attack, in which the attacker knows at least one $(L,C)$ pair?

Comment: Can you please clarify what $T(M,K)$ means? Encryption using plain DES?

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to find T(M,K) anywhere in the question. Triple DES has been used in this case

Comment: Just to be sure at what knowledge level you are: What research have you done? For example, did you search this site for Q&As like [“Why is triple-DES using three different keys vulnerable to a meet-in-the-middle-attack?”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6345/12164) and its accepted answer? That might already answer your question…

Comment: oh, sorry, I was slightly unclear up there then: You write $T(L,K_1)$. Is this plain DES encryption or is it rather full Triple-DES encryption (so you'd be doing 9x DES in this case)?

Comment: It is plain DES encryption I guess..I searched a lot and mostly found the answers when the keys are T((L,k1),k2,k1) and unsure what would happen in this case where it is T(L,k1),k2,k2)

Comment: I *think* this special order *may* allow for a $2^{57}$ time (and $2^{56}$ space) meet-in-the-middle attack, by treating it as plain double encryption using two different ciphers and replacing $T(T(L,K_2),K_2)$ by $U(L,K_2)$ (with two DES calls internally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This illustrates the importance of getting the key order right with 3DES two-key [keying option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options). With the correct order of $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_1$ you get something that [should be impossible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/duration-for-attacking-two-key-triple-des-encryption-using-all-ram-ever-built) to attack with current resources, while with the incorrect order in the question it is feasible to attack.

The outer two encryption layers can be joined into a single cipher, which we may call DES<sup>2</sup>. That is a 64-bit block cipher with a 56-bit key, just like DES. It is approximately twice as expensive to compute.

The question then becomes the simple case of applying the meet-in-the-middle attack to double encryption. The inner cipher is DES, the outer DES<sup>2</sup>. The fastest option is to build the table for the inner encryption encryption in $2^{56}$ DES calls, since you then only need to compute the outer cipher $2^{55}$ times on average (i.e. $2^{56}$ DES calls).

You need memory for a $2^{56}$ item table, unless you apply a time-memory tradeoff. It would be expensive but on the verge of doable even with this brute force approach. You may also be able to get away with a factor of 2 or so fewer calls by [making use of related keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32951/can-the-key-complement-property-of-des-be-used-against-3des). Other improvements are likely possible.